# Creating periodic/looping workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list named reminder_list which has a `DateTime` field called reminder date. 
I want to create a SharePoint designer workflow on that list which will run everyday and check if the reminder date field is equal to current date or not,if it is equal then it will send an email.

Is this possible to do? Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I same question. i have a SPD workflow associated with list but when i add a retention stage and select start a worklow it says "There are no workflows associated with this list. "????

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps solve it:

-Create a workflow that starts when an item is created

-Create a local workflow variable named 'today' (date/time type)

**Stage 1**

Add an action : wait for duration: 24 hours

Set 'today' to Current date

In the transition to stage part of this step add a condition:

If current item 'Reminder date' is greater than 'today' (the workflow variable) Go to stage 2

else go to stage 1 (so repeat the action the next day)

**stage 2:**

actions after reminder date is met.

end of workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can create a retention policy on the list that check the DateTime field for you, and as its action it can run a workflow for you.

Take a look at this like, it will show you how to create the policies.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-HA101631505.aspx

Comment: As mentioned in the above link i went to that list->list settings->information management policy settings->clicked link item->enable retention->clicked add a retention stage but when i select "Start a workflow" in actions it says "there are no workflows associated with this list.select another action" even though i have associated this list with a sample workflow i have created in sharepoint designer

Answer (score 0):

IRM retention policy does not support 2013 workflows. Please try with 2010 workflows instead.

[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0640e051-96db-4916-a7c1-9ffe21d42b73/retention-stage-action-cant-find-associated-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a Powershell or C# timerjob/Azure job that uses Search or just iterates each item looking for Reminder date.
This is particular useful is you are validating more that just the Reminder date and checking content from the entire tenant/farm. 
In my case I am checking that each item has an owner, that the owner is an active user (not ex employee), that the owner is not an extenal user and so on